# Freeswitch with Skype Connect external profile keeps timing out and disconnecting

Tags: sip, voip, skype, telephony, freeswitch

I have a Skype Connect SIP profile set up on a small Freeswitch setup.  All seems fine - I can make incoming and outgoing calls.  Problem is - if there is no activity for a while, incoming calls time out and drop. That is, the caller hears a long ring and then the call drops without connecting.

If I restart Freeswitch, the problem goes away.  If an outgoing call or another incoming call has happened recently, the problem does not occur.

I see frequent messages in my Freeswitch log as follows:

```
2012-10-09 16:12:04.043891 [NOTICE] sofia_reg.c:415 Registering skype
2012-10-09 16:16:51.184120 [NOTICE] sofia_reg.c:415 Registering skype
2012-10-09 16:21:38.324166 [NOTICE] sofia_reg.c:415 Registering skype
```

A call immediately after one of these registrations succeeds.

I am off the opinion that the registration is timing out and dropping.  Upon detection by Freeswitch it reconnects, but during the window when it is down, incoming calls fail.

I have replaced my router which has not made a big pile of difference.

External Sip Profile is as follows:

```xml
<include>
  <gateway name="skype">
  <param name="realm" value="sip.skype.com"/>
  <param name="proxy" value="sip.skype.com"/>
  <param name="from-domain" value="sip.skype.com"/>
  <param name="username" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
  <param name="from-user" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
  <param name="password" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
  <param name="contact-params" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX@sip.skype.com"/>
  <param name="extension" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
  <param name="extension-in-contact" value="true"/>
  <param name="retry-seconds" value="0"/>
  <param name="caller-id-in-from" value="false"/>
  <param name="ping" value="30"/>
  </gateway>
</include>
```

username and password have been replaced with XXXXs for obvious reasons.  any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are not telling FS to send keep-alive packets.

For Natted softphones try this in your **sofia.conf**:
< param name="nat-options-ping" value="true" />

For all registered softphones try:
< param name="all-reg-options-ping" value="true" />

Comment: i've added this into sofia.conf.xml .  Will keep you posted if/if not it fixed the issue.  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, this seems to have fixed the issue.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense to set "expire-seconds" to some low value, and this should force FreeSWITCH to re-register more frequently (default is 3600). Also it makes sense to see what the "expire" parameter is sent back and forth in REGISTER and ACK messages.